# 2-adic valuation of odd harmonic sums

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, harmonic-numbers

I'm playing with p-adic valuations, and find that the odd harmonic sums, $\tilde{H}_k=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2i-1}$, has 2-adic valuation $||k^2||_2=2||k||_2$.

E.g.) $\tilde{H}_4=\frac{176}{85}$ has $||\tilde{H}_4||_2=||176||_2=4=2||4||_2$.

$\tilde{H}_6=\frac{6508}{3465}$ has $||\tilde{H}_6||_2=2$. $||\tilde{H}_8||_2=||\frac{91072}{45045}||_2=6$. $\cdots$

How can I prove this?

(Some simple observation I have tried: As [$||H_k||_2 =-r$ for $2^r\leq k <2^{r+1}$](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/padicharmonicsum.pdf), $||H_k||_2=||H_{2k}||_2+1=||\frac{1}{2}H_k||_2$. Thus ultrametric ineq for $\tilde{H}_k=H_{2k}-\frac{1}{2}H_k$ doesn't help at all, yielding trivial result $\tilde{H}_k\in \mathbb{Z}_2$.)

(That $||\tilde{H}_k||_2=2||k||_2$ for odd $k$ is almost trivial, so the problem can be reduced to show $||\tilde{H}_{2k}||_2=||\tilde{H}_k||_2+2$, still have no idea)

(I've checked this holds up to $\sim 1000$ using Mathematica, and Mathematica spits the result almost immediately for $n\sim 1000$ and takes about a minute for $n\sim 10000$. )

For anyone interested : I've used the following Mathematica code, try it yourself

`a = Table[
   IntegerExponent[
     Numerator[HarmonicNumber[2 n] - HarmonicNumber[n]/2], 2]/2, {n, 
    10000}];
b = Table [IntegerExponent[n, 2], {n, 10000}];
NonNegative[Min[a - b]]`

Comment: If we can show that a partial sum
$$\tilde{H}_{2^k,m}=\sum_{i=m\cdot2^k+1}^{(m+1)\cdot2^k}\frac1{2i-1}$$ of length a power of two always has 2-adic value $=2k$, then your conjecture would follow, right? My testing (with Mathematica) supports this as well, but it is anything but comprehensive.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, maybe this form is a little bit easier but I have no idea how to show this too :(

Comment: It looks like you use $\|\cdot\|_2$ for the additive $2$-adic valuation. This symbol usual means multiplicative $2$-adic absolute value.

Answer (score 2):

Only  a partial result. I note  $v_2$ the $2$-adic valuation.

Let $\displaystyle Q_k(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}(x-j)=x^{k}+b_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\cdots+b_0$. We have $b_l\in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that $b_{k-1}=-\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. Put $P_k(x)=2^kQ_k(\frac{x}{2})$. Then $P_k(x)=x^{k}+2b_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\cdots+2^{k-1}b_1 x+2^k b_0=\prod_{j=1}^{k}(x-2j)$.

Now
$$\frac{P_k^{\prime}(x)}{P_k(x)}=\sum_{j=1}^k \frac{1}{x-2j}$$ Putting $x=1$, we get that $v_2(\tilde{H_k})=v_2(P_k^{\prime}(1))$.

Now suppose that $k$ is odd. Then $P_k^{\prime}(1)=k+2q$ with $q\in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence your result is true in this case (as you have noted).

Suppose that $k=2m$ with $m$ odd.Then the first two terms in $P_k^{\prime}(1)$ give $ (2m-(2m(2m+1)(2m-1))=4m(1-2m^2)$, and it is easy to see that $8$ divide the other terms. Hence your result is true in this case.