# Find the highest power of $2$ which divides the numerator of $H_{k}=1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2k-1}$

Tags: number-theory

**Question:**

> Let $k$ be give the postive integers,Find the highest power of $2$ which divides the numerator of
>   $$H_{k}=1+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2k-1}$$

I found some case
when $k=2$,then
$$H_{2}=1+\dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{4}{3}$$,because the numerator $4$ havethe highest power of is $2$

when $k=3$,then
$$H_{3}=1+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}=\dfrac{23}{15}$$because the numerator $23$have the highest power of is $0$

when $k=4$,then
$$H_{4}=1+\dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{1}{5}+\dfrac{1}{7}=\dfrac{176}{105}$$because the numerator $144$ have the highest power of is $4$

**So I conjecture this problem answer is $2V_{2}(k)$.then How to prove？**

Comment: What is $V_2(k)$?

Comment: where $V_{p}(n)$  denotes the largest power of $p$ that divides $n$

Comment: Duplicate of  [2-adic valuation of odd harmonic sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1860105/42969)? – Also [2-adic valuation of odd harmonic sums](https://mathoverflow.net/q/244430) on Math Overflow.